# In Elasticsearch, why isn't my multi-line script working?

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I'm using the Elasticsearch JavaScript API.

The following script works in the sense that it runs without error:

```
const script = {
  "lang": "painless",
  "source": `
  for (int i = 0; i < ctx._source.metadata.length; ++i) {
  }
  `,
};
```

But when I try and use three double quotes as in the following example:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/master/painless-examples.html#_accessing_doc_values_from_painless

(because my script is going to be a complex multi-line one), I modify my code to:

```
const script = {
  "lang": "painless",
  "source": `
  """
  for (int i = 0; i < ctx._source.metadata.length; ++i) {
  }
  """
  `,
};
```

and then I get the following error:

> "reason\":\"unexpected token ['\\"\\n      for (int i = 0; i <
>   ctx._source.metadata.length; ++i) {\\n      }\\n      \\"'] was
>   expecting one of [{, ';'}].\"}},\"status\":500}"}

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, multiline strings can be done with `. There is no need for the """. The documentation you reference is not for JavaScript.

> ... because my script is going to be a complex multi-line one

... But your first example also shows a multiline code and that works?